# Query on historical data - new/removed entries

Tags: sql, sql-server, view

Could someone please advise on a query to get sum of new and removed entries per period?

I have a table, containing historical data like this (with PKI on GUID+Date)
Table 1

```
GUID       Date          Category
----------------------------------
00001   2020-04-01         A  
00002   2020-04-01         B
00003   2020-04-01         C

00001   2020-04-02         A
00002   2020-04-02         B
00003   2020-04-02         C
00004   2020-04-02         A

00001   2020-04-03         A
00002   2020-04-03         B
00003   2020-04-03         C
00004   2020-04-03         A
00007   2020-04-03         A
00005   2020-04-03         B

00001   2020-04-04         A
00002   2020-04-04         B
00004   2020-04-04         A
00007   2020-04-04         A
00005   2020-04-04         B
```

As a result I need to get the sum of guid during period (min date in the month) which were added and removed.

In this example it would be

Table 2

```
Status    Period        Category  Amount
----------------------------------------
  New     2020-04-01        A        2
  New     2020-04-01        B        1
Removed   2020-04-01        C        1
```

Thanks for any advice and help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you want to compare the first and last appearances of each guid.  I'm assuming the category doesn't change during the month.

If that is correct, you can use aggregation:

```
select (case when max_date < data_max_date then 'removed'
             when min_date > data_min_date then 'new'
        end) as status,
       category, count(*)
from (select guid, category, min(date) as min_date, max(date) as max_date,
             min(min(date)) over () as data_min_date,
             max(max(date)) over () as data_max_date
      from t
      group by guid, category
     ) gc
where min_date <> data_min_date or max_date <> data_max_date
group by category;
```

Comment: Hi @Gordon Linoff,
as a result I get something like this on my dataset, is it doing the calculation per day in this case?
`status Category Quantity`
`removed    A              7
removed B 9
new D 4
removed D 1
new B 2
new B 13
new C 1
new B 4
removed A 1
removed B 1
removed A 3
removed A 1
removed A 1
new D 1
removed D 1
new D 17
removed C 1
removed B 28
new B 3
new D 10
removed B 5
removed B 5
new D 1
removed D 1
new D 1
removed C 2
removed C 1
new D 8
new A 3
new A 11
new C 1
new A 14
removed D 2
removed D 1
removed D 1
new D 6`

Comment: @Rudyi . . . Perhaps you should set up a SQL/DB fiddle of some sort.